# Create two table with laravel migration with references

Tags: php, laravel, reference, migration, laravel-artisan

I need to create two tables:
First `articles`:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('roba_spremna');
            $table->timestamp('auction_end');
            $table->string('key');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

and then `offers`:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('article_id');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('article_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('articles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` I get:

[image]

What is the problem? Why I cant create succesfully this two tables?

Comment: The table already exists in your db...Check your db manually..

Answer (score 1):

It's because table is already created.  Delete table and re run.

Comment: I try to drop table and re run migration but I get: PS
PS C:\wamp\www\learn5> php artisan migrate:refresh
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Impossible d'ajouter des contraintes d'index externe (SQL: alter table `offers
  ` add constraint offers_article_id_foreign foreign key (`article_id`) references `articles` (`id`) on delete cascad
  e)  [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215Impossible d'ajouter des contraintes d'index externe

Comment: It seemes you need to drop whole database and re un.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference `id` column of a table your column needs to be unsigned, the `article_id` column in `offers` table is not unsigned , make it unsigned and refresh the migration